# Set "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS" attribute ON/OFF for a pyodbc connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to create a connection to a SQL Server 11.0.5058 using pyodbc package in my python code, and would like to know if it is possible to set the property 'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' to On/OFF using the pyodbc connection object.
I need to set this property on my connection object so that I can execute a stored procedure, and NOT have an implicit transaction ON during this transaction. The stored procedures I have only select from views, and no updates or alters.

Connection String that I am using:

```
            self.connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, timeout=TIMEOUT_FOR_QUERY,
                                         attrs_before={SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: TIMEOUT_FOR_CONNECTION},
                                         autocommit=False)
```

Execute Stored Procedure code snippet ( I just pass the stored procedure name, and parameters):

```
                stringToProcess = '{CALL ' + stored_procedure_name + ' (' + nbofParamt_str + ')}'

            self.cursor.execute(stringToProcess , tuple(parameters))
```

P.S. I don't have SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS {On | OFF} in my stored_procedure script. Do I need to set this in the script, and not in the pyodbc connection object?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server version 11.0.5058 is 2012 SP2. SP2 has known security vulnerabilities. Is there any reason you haven't at least installed the GDR update? SP4 came out 3 years ago though (which too, has a GDR update). Why has your server not been patched?

Comment: @Larnu Appreciate your feedback here, but 'why not server being patched' is not  adding any value here, until it relates to the implcit_transaction attribute. Also TBH I don't have any view on the patching.

Comment: With all due respect, but how is alerting you to the fact that the software that you are using having security vulnerabilities not giving you value? No, it's not related to your question, however, it is warning you that you **need** to patch your server. It's running a 5 year old release of a version of SQL Server that's only in extended support. Security is important.

Answer (score -2):

With ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and current versions of SQL Server the default is

```
set implicit_transactions off
```

If you think the situation might be different in your environment you can check it using the following T-SQL snippet from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
DECLARE @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (2 & @@OPTIONS) = 2 ) SET @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = 'ON';  
SELECT @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS AS IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS;
```

If you want IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to be ON just set it yourself before calling the SP.

We can use the above code in a little stored procedure to verify:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE so60511929 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
    IF ( (2 & @@OPTIONS) = 2 ) SET @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = 'ON';  
    SELECT @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS AS IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS;
END
```

Then, from Python:

```py
import pyodbc

def check_implicit_transactions(con: pyodbc.Connection) -> str:
    return (
        "IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is "
        f"{con.execute('{CALL so60511929}').fetchval()}"
    )

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    "DSN=mssql_199;UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH"
)
print(f"autocommit is {cnxn.autocommit}")
# autocommit is False
print(check_implicit_transactions(cnxn))
# IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is OFF

cnxn.autocommit = True
print(f"autocommit is {cnxn.autocommit}")
# autocommit is True
print(check_implicit_transactions(cnxn))
# IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is OFF

cnxn.execute("SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON")
print(check_implicit_transactions(cnxn))
# IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON
```